# Pass data from partial view to controller method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to partial views. I want to pass data from partial view to controller method. can anyone suggest me how to pass it utilizing jQuery ? .. can we implement ajax in partial view?

Comment: You can implement anything in partial views. Beside technical details, basically the only difference from non-partial views is that partial views are rendered without layout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may take any approach you use in Views: Html.BeginForm(), @Ajax.BeginForm() or jQuery